# How to set array of different objects (NSString, UIImage,NSString,etc) to a message body of MFMessageViewController in Same Order in array

Tags: ios, message

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *msgComposer=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];            
msgComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
msgComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"9688069434",nil];
msgComposer.body = @"Message Body";
[self presentViewController:msgComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The Property "body" is NSString. Then I have tried attachments.

How to Assign NSArray to Messagebody?

Comment: You can't. The message body is just text (though the text can be HTML). You can append the text elements together and add the images as attachments. That's about your only option.

Comment: I have tried HTML also. But it didn't work.